# Proof Verification for presentation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Can someone verify or discredit my proof? Help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid that you’ve completely misunderstood what the lexicographical order on $A\times B$ is. It’s defined as follows:

> For $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle,\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\in A\times B$, $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle\preceq_{A\times B}\langle a_1,b_1\rangle$ if and only if either $a_0\prec_A a_1$, or $a_0=a_1$ and $b_0\preceq_B b_1$.

The ordered pairs that you’re comparing are the elements of $A\times B$, **not** (as in your answer) the elements of $\{A,\preceq_A\}\times\{B,\preceq_B\}$.

Here’s a simple example. Let $A=\wp(\{0,1\})=\big\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\big\}$, with the partial order $\subseteq$, and let $B=\{a,b,c\}$, with $\preceq_B$ being alphabetical order (i.e., $a\prec b\prec c$). Then the elements of $A\times B$ are:

$$\begin{align*}
&\langle\varnothing,a\rangle,\langle\varnothing,b\rangle,\langle\varnothing,c\rangle,\\
&\langle\{0\},a\rangle,\langle\{0\},b\rangle,\langle\{0\},c\rangle,\\
&\langle\{1\},a\rangle,\langle\{1\},b\rangle,\langle\{1\},c\rangle,\\
&\langle\{0,1\},a\rangle,\langle\{0,1\},b\rangle,\langle\{0,1\},c\rangle\;.
\end{align*}$$

Then for instance $\langle\{1\},c\rangle\prec_{A\times B}\langle\{0,1\},a\rangle$, because $\{1\}\subsetneqq\{0,1\}$, and $\langle\{1\},a\rangle\prec_{A\times B}\langle\{1\},c\rangle$, because $\{1\}=\{1\}$ and $a\prec_B c$.